What does the tcp_info struct tcpi_rtt field measure exactly?
I have an AWS instance and I receive TCP from a third-party instance within the same AWS region. I think they use a load balancer.
I want to measure the latency from source.
I'm extracting the Linux tcp_info object and querying tcpi_rtt, the TCP round trip time (RTT) is 20 ms. So, 10 ms one way.
However, each TCP payload/application message contains an Epoch timestamp and implies the message took 1-2 ms.
Why is the Linux TCP RTT value 10 ms but the application timestamp implies 1-2 ms?
I'm aware of NTP and PTP, clock skew etc, although as both machines are inside AWS and the latency of 1-2 ms seems sensible, this seems to be the true latency. However, I would assume the TCP RTT latency is credible.
What's happening here? Is the TCP RTT a 99th percentile, updated periodically?

variation of packet sizes causes a large variation in RTT https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122 : The performance increase resulting from the use of these improvements varies from noticeable to dramatic.
acobson's algorithm for incorporating the measured RTT
variance is especially important on a low-speed link,
where the natural variation of packet sizes causes a
large variation in RTT.  One vendor found link
utilization on a 9.6kb line went from 10% to 90% as a
result of implementing Jacobson's variance algorithm in
TCP.
